# Duplicate entry for primary key error for kettke transformation(job)

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have 1-table input 1-row filter 1-table output in my spoon transformation. I put this transformation in a Job.

I am getting error:

> " Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1000' for
>   key 'PRIMARY'

I have checked the input table but there it has only one entry for primary `key = 1000.` can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: The error indicates that it occurs on the table output step. Are you sure the entry doesn't exist already in the output table?

Comment: based on my transformation design, if the table input has only one entry for primary key then table output should have only one entry. I have checked there is only one entry in table input. but still table output is inserting it again, pls find my transformation here https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hC76HYdt-mE/XJnhBi3L8DI/AAAAAAAAnKU/GLRbc8kXAYwiGXPlPf0KcBlkgnZGrJijACK8BGAs/s0/3694910723253787613%253Faccount_id%253D1
             "transformation"

Comment: Is the output table cleared/truncated before each run of the transformation? The table output step, in contrast to the insert/update step, does not check if the output table already contains the row to write and will fail when the database server complains about the violated constraint on the primary key (as it is not unique). If the transformation should run multiple times, then an insert/update step would be better.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time i am running the transformation. table is truncated and then running the transformation.

Comment: Okay, those were my first two guesses as to what's wrong. Could you update the question with the code of the transformation? An image isn't helping much. You can find out the code by opening the kettle file (.ktr) with a text editor and copying the entire XML content. PLEASE make sure to edit out the database connection credentials.

Comment: Here is the link for the xml file. I have changed some fileds name. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pZRNZ0vIBTmp5xYBJSvRoy5r_aY1MKj3

Comment: I noticed that in the ```Filter rows``` step, you did not specify to which steps the filtered and filtered-out rows should be send. Usually one step will further work with the filtered rows and the filtered-out rows are sent to a dummy step or maybe a logging step. Either way, I don't think this is what causes your problem. Sorry I couldn't be of help after all. Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick responses.